# Parse and get specific part from sting

Tags: c#, parsing

I have an ugly string:

```
a1a5021a96188bbfa7d\" alt=\"\" \/>\u003C\/a>\u003Cdiv class=\"_8u _42ef\">\u003Cdiv class=\"_6a _5u5j\">\u003Cdiv class=\"_6a _6b\" style=\"height:100px\">\u003C\/div>\u003Cdiv class=\"_6a _5u5j _6b\">\u003Cdiv class=\"fsl fwb fcb\">\u003Ca href=\"https:\/\/www.facebook.com\/username.ivn?fref=grp_mmbr_list\" data-hovercard=\"\/ajax\/hovercard\/user.php?id=100002759468783&extragetparams=\u00257B\u002522fref\u002522\u00253A\u002522grp_mmbr_list\u002522\u00257D\">Mamu Ivaniadze\u003C\/a>\u003C\/div>
```

How to get the part of `user.php?id=100002759468783`  from it. In reality it's a big string and I need to get all ids  `user.php?id=someId`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use this regular expression:

```regex
(user\.php\?id=[0-9]+)
```

It will always get you the user URL part and the id out. Use `Regex.Match` or `Regex.Matches` (in case of multiple possible results) to match the input string and use the capture(s) to get the URL out.

Comment: See the code sample on [`Regex.Matches`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b49yw9s8(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You don't parse HTML using regular expressions.

1. Parse the HTML using HtmlAgilityPack.
2. Obtain all `a` tags that have an `data-hovercard` attribute, and select that attribute value.
3. Now you have a list of strings, representing relative URIs.
4. Parse the URIs and obtain the query string.
5. Parse the query string and obtain the value of the `id` key.

Comment: I am using HtmlAgilityPack but in this case not works